# Swift, How to access IBOutletCollection of UIButton randomly

Tags: arrays, swift, button

I am using swift on Xcode 7.3,

I have created an IBOutletCollection for few buttons.
Now I want to change a random button's size in this collection, but I don't know how to access it.
Nomaly you write: self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)

question is how to write line with collection, or array, using arc4random.

I hope my question is clear,

thanks,

Comment: What is a UIButtonCollection?

Comment: Where did you get Xcode 7.3?

Comment: It's an array, how have you tried to generate a random index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of getting a random Element from an Array this should solve your problem. If you Collection is an array. It uses the arc4random_uniform method the parameter is the number which is the upper bound for random number so, in the example it will return a number between 0 and 3. The Int() building an swift in from the Objective c data type which is returned by arc4random. Hope this solution works for you.

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5]
test[Int(arc4random_uniform(4))]
```

Comment: Hey i See you are quite new to stack overflow if my answer solved your problem it would be nice if you mark it as correct answer & if like the answer to vote it up :)

Comment: Sorry, this was my first question, your answer was really helpful and it solved my problem. thanks again :)